# how to display nested HTML table with master/detail info from XML file

Tags: html, jquery, xml

i have this xml and i want to read/process XML file using jQuery and put it in a nested table such as this

```
 Student No  0001 
 Name    May 
 Subject Code    Description      Units   Professor
 IPT              IPT              3         Jes
  WD               Web Devt         3         Mark
Student No  0002
Name    June 
Subject Code    Description      Units     Professor 
IPT              IPT              3           Jes
```

this is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enrollment>
    <student>
        <stud_no>0001</stud_no>
        <stud_name>May</stud_name>
            <enrollment_data>
                <subj_code>IPT</subj_code>
                <subj_desc>Integrative Programming and Technologies</subj_desc>
                <subj_units>3</subj_units>
                <professor>Jes</professor>
            </enrollment_data>
            <enrollment_data>
                <subj_code>WD</subj_code>
                <subj_desc>Web Devt</subj_desc>
                <subj_units>3</subj_units>
                <professor>Mark</professor>
            </enrollment_data>
    </student>
    <student>
        <stud_no>0002</stud_no>
        <stud_name>June</stud_name>
            <enrollment_data>
                <subj_code>IPT</subj_code>
                <subj_desc>Integrative Programming and Technologies</subj_desc>
                <subj_units>3</subj_units>
                <professor>Jes</professor>
            </enrollment_data>
    </student>
</enrollment>
```

```
<table id="employee" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Subject Code</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Units</th>
<th>Professor</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
 
<script>

   $.ajax({
        url: "xml_sample2.xml",
        type:"POST",    
        success: function(xml){
        alert(xml);
            //xml = $.parseXML(xml);
            xml = $(xml);
            student = xml.find("student");
            student.each(function(){
            var snum=$(this).find("stud_no").text();
            var name=$(this).find("stud_name").text();
            $("#employee tbody").append("<tr><td>"+ snum +"</td><td>"+ name +"</td>");
        
            details = xml.find("enrollment_data");
            details.each(function(){
                var scode=$(this).find("subj_code").text();
                var title=$(this).find("subj_desc").text();
                var units=$(this).find("subj_units").text();
                var prof=$(this).find("professor").text();
                    $("#employee tbody").append("<tr><td>"+ scode +"</td><td>"+ title +"</td><td>"+ units +"</td><td>"+ prof +"</td></tr>");
            });
            });
        }
    });
  
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Did you try to [research your question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+xml+to+html+table) before posting it?

Comment: yes i updated my post. im stuck

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: i cant format it like the one i posted with master/detail info. how can display nested table from xml with master detail info.

Comment: Please add those details in your question as well.

Comment: First, not sure your table structure is best for that type of data. Second, this can be done simply with pure javascript.

Comment: pls how to do it in pure js?

Comment: some of those `var` can be `const` or `let` perhaps

Answer (score 0):

With pure JS, you can do something like the below.

The basic concepts are these: First, your data is in xml format so you should parse it with an xml parser; that the job of [DOMParser()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). Next, to query the xml data you should use xpath, incorporated in JS in the form of [the document.evaluate() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate). Finally, you convert the search results into html using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and insert them into the table using the [insertAdjacentHTML() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

As I mentioned, I changed the structure of the table a little so it makes more sense (to me), but you can obviously play with it and use another format.

So all together:

```js
xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enrollment>
    <student>
        <stud_no>0001</stud_no>
        <stud_name>May</stud_name>
            <enrollment_data>
                <subj_code>IPT</subj_code>
                <subj_desc>Integrative Programming and Technologies</subj_desc>
                <subj_units>3</subj_units>
                <professor>Jes</professor>
            </enrollment_data>
            <enrollment_data>
                <subj_code>WD</subj_code>
                <subj_desc>Web Devt</subj_desc>
                <subj_units>3</subj_units>
                <professor>Mark</professor>
            </enrollment_data>
    </student>
    <student>
        <stud_no>0002</stud_no>
        <stud_name>June</stud_name>
            <enrollment_data>
                <subj_code>IPT</subj_code>
                <subj_desc>Integrative Programming and Technologies</subj_desc>
                <subj_units>3</subj_units>
                <professor>Jes</professor>
            </enrollment_data>
    </student>
</enrollment>
`;
const docEval = (doc, expr, context) =>
  doc.evaluate(expr, context, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

domdoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
dest = document.querySelector("#theTable");
stus = docEval(domdoc, './/student', domdoc);

for (let i = 0; i < stus.snapshotLength; i++) {
let student = stus.snapshotItem(i);
  studNo = docEval(domdoc, ".//stud_no/text()", student);
  studName = docEval(domdoc, ".//stud_name/text()", student); 
  row = `<tr style="background-color:powderblue;">
     <td>${studNo.snapshotItem(0).textContent}</td>
     <td>${studName.snapshotItem(0).textContent}</td>
 </tr>`;
  dest.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", row);
  infos = docEval(domdoc, ".//enrollment_data", student);

  for (let i = 0; i < infos.snapshotLength; i++) {
    let entry = infos.snapshotItem(i);
    subjCode = docEval(domdoc, ".//subj_code/text()", entry);
    subjDesc = docEval(domdoc, ".//subj_desc/text()", entry);
    subjUnit = docEval(domdoc, ".//subj_units/text()", entry);
    prof = docEval(domdoc, ".//professor/text()", entry);
    row2 = `<tr style="background-color:yellow;">
      <td>${subjCode.snapshotItem(0).textContent}</td>
      <td>${subjDesc.snapshotItem(0).textContent}</td>
      <td>${subjUnit.snapshotItem(0).textContent}</td>
      <td>${prof.snapshotItem(0).textContent}</td>
   </tr>`;
    dest.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", row2);
  }

}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://edwardtufte.github.io/tufte-css/tufte.css" type="text/css">
<body>
<table id='theTable' border='1'><tr>
<td>id&CourseCode</td>
<td>Name&Subject</td>
<td>Units</td>
<td>Prof</td>
</tr></table>
</body>
```

Comment: This is good but might be better with less undeclared variables.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  There's always room for improvement; unfortunately, that takes time - which is not always readily available...

Comment: thank you. but are there any more approach to do this?

Comment: @MichaelAcosta - What do you mean?

Comment: like can i do it in jquery?

Comment: @MichaelAcosta I don't use jquery so I don't really know. IIUC, jquery's xpath support is limited and when I deal with xml that's not good enough.